# turning an image to a link

Tags: html, css

i'm experimenting in school with turning an image into a link but so far the link is not contained to the image but the entire row and i have tried looking at several example but none have worked for me so far. here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Alpha page</title>
  </head>
  <p>The image is a link. You can click on it.</p>

  <a href="https://www.youtube.com">
    <img src="youtube.png" alt="Youtube">
  </a>

  <p>We have added "border:0" to prevent IE9 (and earlier) from displaying a border around the image.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your html is messed up: You are closing the `<head/>` you never opened inside your `<body>`.

Comment: To clarify Filburts comment, valid document setup is `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head></head><body><body></html>` Also note that you should close all tags. For example `<link>` and `<meta>`. They don't have a closing tag, therefor use `<link rel="..." />`

Comment: The start and end tags for the HTML, HEAD and BODY elements are all optional (both in theory (the spec) and in practice (browsers). The `/` at the end of a link element is also optional, it is allowed only because some people got used to writing XHTML.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ruvufoqawe/1/edit?html,output — I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: the link is the image, dont see an issue

Answer (score 0):

I think i know what you mean, but enlighten me if im wrong.

Your trying to use `png` image but link is also working if u click outside the visible image. (white area) This is because the link is the full image of the `H x W`

**Example**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Alpha page</title>
</head>
<p>The image is a link. You can click on it.</p>

<a href="https://www.youtube.com">
  <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-icons-5/607/YouTube_Play.png" alt="Youtube">
</a>

<p>We have added "border:0" to prevent IE9 (and earlier) from displaying a border around the image.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

If you want only a certain area you will have to use `image-map`.  [W3 LINK](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)

I have used [this site](https://www.image-map.net/) to ease the time.

**Example**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Alpha page</title>
  </head>
  <p>The image is a link. You can click on it.</p>

  <map name="image-map">
    <area target="" alt="youtube" title="" href="https://www.youtube.com" coords="304,303,302" shape="circle">
</map>
  <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-icons-5/607/YouTube_Play.png" usemap="#image-map">

  </a>

  <p>We have added "border:0" to prevent IE9 (and earlier) from displaying a border around the image.</p>

</body>

</html>
```